# How to do a search method on a many2many model in odoo12?

Tags: python, odoo-12

i have to browse a many2many model and fetch the datas in it.
Many2many model = model_model2_rel
i tried like `self.env['model1.model2.rel'].search([('field', 'in', self.fields.id)])`

But when i tried a key error on model name is coming,which is the proper way to do this?

Comment: according to my limited knowledge I think `many2many` is not a model. It is just a field type. Secondly whenever you created many2many field it will create new table not new model at background.

Comment: @Adam Strauss Actually what im trying to do is We can create a many2many field and giive it as a notebook right?I have to do the same in the frontend using modal,bootstrap.So i have to get the datas from the many2many model